# Finding where data levels off and rise times

Tags: matlab

My data looks like this: 
[image]

I am trying to find the following info about my data:

Rate of rise on the "transient" portion

time to steady state and steady state average

I think that stepinfo is my best bet to do this, but it seems to want take the final value as the steady state value which isn't giving me the best result. And I cannot find the average value of the steady time until I know when it is.... Is there a way to set some bounds on the steady state search? On the picture i linked it could be data within +/- 0.25 for 50 data points is steady state?

Comment: I don't really see a clear distinction between transient and steady state in your image. To me it looks like an exponential approach to a constant; any way to dissect this into "transient" and "steady state" will be arbitrary. If you are forced to make such a dissection, the right way to do so will depend critically on your application.

Comment: @A.Donda There is clearly a ramp up period on that graph followed by a  plateau , I want to find the point where the slope levels off I suppose and the rate of change in the data is no longer high. It will be arbitrary to some extent but how can I get as close as possible to finding that point? If you look at the actual data not the fit line you can see that the data is somewhat oscillating and not exponential.

Comment: Could you provide your data?

Comment: @Benoit_11 not easily at the moment, the file is quite large and on another computer. it looks really similar to the data in the figure thouguh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is:

1. Decide what the slope of the curve should be in the intersection between transient and steady state
2. Smoothen you signal
3. Find the difference between each point on the graph
4. Find the first place where the difference between points is lower then the value you selected in

To do this, keep in mind:

- The difference in the beginning is on average zero, thus you have to skip these values.
  One way to do this is simply: `x(x < 0.1 * max(x)) = [];` That way you remove the entire start of the curve. You won't need it for this part anyway. Remember to keep a backup of `x`.
- A simple way to smoothen the signal is: `smooth_x = arrayfun(@(t) mean(x(t:t+k)), 1:numel(x-k))`. You need to find an appropriate value for `k`.
- Even a smoothed curve will have "bumps", thus you might want to compare points that are not adjacent, for instance check `diff(x(k),x(k+10))`. If the average incline between those two points are lower than the value you selected in 1, you're happy. A combination of `find` and `diff` should do the trick here.

Once you have smoothed it, you can use `diff` to find the average inclination for both the transient and the stable part.
There is no way for me to tell where the curve goes from transient to stable. That's a decision you need to make. It could for instance be less than 0.2 l/min per 10 seconds.

Comment: I smoothed my signal using lowess in the curve fitting toolbox, how do I find the slope of this smoothed data?

Comment: @excelhelp: Try `diff(y)/diff(x)`. I can't help you more at the moment I'm afraid. Good luck =)